# 'Infinite' Zoom Gallery – Is there a Non-Flash (Java + HTML5 +CSS3) way to achieve this effect?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, flash, canvas

Quick early morning question.
I came across this French website and I reallt like the effect on their portfolio page: http://www.lasourissurlegateau.com/#/book/

It's like you're zooming in on the projects instead of scrolling. Now, from what I can tell this was achieved using Flash. Is there a way to achieve a similar effect using only Javascript and/or HTML5 with CSS3?

If so, any links or tutorials would be much appreciated! 
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try [`impress.js`](http://bartaz.github.io/impress.js/#/step-3)

That looks quite interesting and seems like it could fulfill your needs.

Comment: I'm a bit confused, that's just a left/right slider, isn't it?

Comment: @CasperF no =) its qite impressive, just press the spacebar a frw times and you'll see